# Log user out of apostrophe-cms after period of inactivity

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I don't see a way to setup apostrophe to automatically log a user out after a period of inactivity. Did I miss something in the documentation or is there a way to implement this built in already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions automatically expire after 24 hours. This is set as an option in the `apostrophe-express` module's `session.cookie` subproperty: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/modules/apostrophe-express.html#options

Comment: thanks, I looked for this for much longer than I should have considering how obvious it was once you pointed it out!